# Uninstall an MSI during during Inno Setup uninstall

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup

I install an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file as part of my Inno Setup install script. Is there a way to also uninstall it as part of the uninstall process for my program?

Comment: Lex Li has already given you an example of how to do it -- I'll just add that sometimes the best choice is not to do it.  Specifically, when the MSI has its own Programs and Features entry, it means that the user will still have the option to uninstall it after they uninstall your app, so you will need to consider whether it's possible that either the user themselves or some other app they've installed may still require that app/component for something.  If in doubt, it's better to ask the user or to just leave it there than to risk breaking another app (since it usually won't be obvious why).

Comment: Do MSI's have some sort of a dependency counter that says how many programs are using them?

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt it.  The typical behaviour is to not even run the MSI if the component is already installed, which means it wouldn't have an opportunity to update its counter anyway, even if it did have one.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to learn what is the GUID of that MSI package,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370568(v=vs.85).aspx

as after installation, it will be registered under `'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (or its WOW64 one).

Once you know the GUID, it can be uninstalled by calling

`MsiExec.exe /X{A879B90E-B62C-4DA4-9C3F-79A1A6CFAAF9}`

Here {A879B90E-B62C-4DA4-9C3F-79A1A6CFAAF9} is an example for "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages - Visual Studio 2010 Tools".

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot variants to do it. With batch:

```
@echo off
  setlocal
    set "key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    set raw=%key%\%%i
    for /f "tokens=7 delims=\" %%i in ('reg query %key%') do (
      if "%%i"=="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" (
        for /f "skip=4 tokens=2,*" %%j in ('reg query "%raw%" /v UninstallString') do (
          rem This command iniatlize uninstallation of .NET Framework
          start /wait "%%k"
        )
      )
    )
  endlocal
exit /b
```

With wmic:

```
wmic Product where Name="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" call Uninstall
```

And more.

**P.S>**"Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" is here for just an example.