# Calling EXE bootstrapper from Add/Remove Programs

Tags: wix, windows-installer, inno-setup, bootstrapper

I have two MSI installation packages (done using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX)), `a.msi` and `b.msi` which are bootstrapped into one EXe file using [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup) resulting in `c.exe`. In the Add/Remove programs only `a.msi` is listed.

The problem is when the user removes `a.msi` from Add/Remove programs I have a custom action in WiX which is triggered that calls `b.msi` to uninstall. Now `b.msi` will fail to uninstall because `a.msi` is in the process of uninstalling and Windows will not let two instances of uninstallers run in parallel.

What I wanted to ask is, can I set the Add/Remove programs to call the `c.exe` bootstrapper such that I can remove both `a.msi` and `b.msi`?

Note: `b.msi` is coming from an external source, and I cannot change it.

Comment: Side issue: If b.msi comes from an external source, are you sure that the user doesn't have another need for it? If you use a WiX Bootstrapper (aka burn), you can mark b.msi as permanent (as far as the bootstrapper is concerned). Anyway, with a WiX Bootstrapper, you have independent control over the bootstrapper, a.msi and b.msi appearing in Add/Remove programs.

Comment: because b.msi will check the registry to see if anyone else is using it, if no it wil uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An installer made in Inno Setup automatically adds itself to *Add/Remove programs*.

If you do not have it there, you had to explicitly disable that using `Uninstallable=no` directive. Just enable it.

---

Regarding how to uninstall .msi from Inno Setup uninstaller, see:
[Uninstall an MSI during during Inno Setup uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19806224/850848)

Comment: yes that was it. 
Thank you :)
I didn't start the installers myself from scratch so I didn't know all the details.
Thanks again

Comment: @Martin, the symptoms points to `CreateUninstallRegKey` rather than global `Uninstallable`, but you were lucky here :)