Uninstall older MSI installation in Inno Setup
I am building a new version of a program with inno Setup.
I am very new at this so bear with me :)
There is an older version of the program NOT created with Inno Setup.
I want to uninstall this before installing the new version.
I did not build it, and I know there is things that are not in the same places in the registry, and I don´t know all so there must be an uninstall of the old version.
I can find the appid with command Run > shell:appsfolder
The appid seems to be the same for many apps but with different endings:
{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\****\****\****\****.exe

However I can not find it in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ 
or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Can someone please help me define the code to uninstall the old version?
Thanks in advance
I have read much about it, but all refer either to older versions created with Inno Setup, or the registry in which I can not find the uninstall.
I don't really understand the answer in this thread. Can I use the same?
Executing UninstallString in Inno Setup

First, how would you uninstall the previous version manually? Can you find a link to uninstall it in Control Panel? What installer does the previous version use?

It can be uninstalled in controlpanel/uninstall program.

I think the installer was built directly in Visual Studio.
It doesnt say anything special when the program is installed, it is an .MSI file.
Or actually 2 files in the zip. 1 .exe and one .msi , I think the exe is to check if .net framework is installed and install if needen, and then execute the .msi file which is the program installer.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/19806224/850848

Ok. I have read through that page, but as I wrote in the beginning. I am new to this and do not know how to add this to my script.
And also. how to find the specific .msi?
I cant find it under 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall (or its WOW64 one)
This is all I found to identify it from "run/shell:appsfolder"
{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}****.exe
Tjis is what I want.
MsiExec.exe /X{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}****.exe /VERYSILENT /NORESTART

So you know the command you need to run to uninstall the MSI? (Though MsiExec does not have /VERYSILENT /NORESTART parameters – those are Inno Setup parameters).

Ok I´m just trying to learn this so I dont know the command to to run the uninstall.
I guess this is what I should write /quiet insted of /VERY SILENT ?
/NORESTART seems to be the same.
But I guess the big problem is that I cant find the app in
'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall (or its WOW64 one)
or can one write MsiExec.exe /X{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}.exe /quite /norestart even though it is a .exe file?
Will the uninstaller know what {7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}.exe is?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/21491631/850848#48296387 + While not really relevant for your question, I believe that if you see the link in the Control Panel, the application must be listed in one of the three Uninstall keys.

I finally found the correct appid. :) when I used powershell according to the link you gave. I have now found it in the WOW6432 node
So now the question is, what and where do I write in the code to execute the msiexec?
I want the uninstall as first thing. And I guess this will be the parameters.
MsiExec.exe /X{***} /quiet /norestart

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000296/850848#2099805 – Just update the detection to be based on the MSI Product Id instead of Inno Setup AppId.

In the last post in that link It is written.
Follow this link: http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup/msg55323.html
In InitializeSetup() function, you can call "MSIEXEC /x {your program ID}" after user prompt to uninstall old old version
The link is dead.
I´m just trying to figure out what to write the code.
Is this correct? What to write? and where?
[Setup]
MSIEXEC /x {your program ID}
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
AppId={{your new program ID}
AppName={#MyAppName}

Why are you trying to follow the worst answer to that question with score -9? Follow the top answer with score +124. + I've already wrote above that you should not use AppId. The AppId is Inno Setup thing. There no AppId involved in an MSI uninstallation. MSI uses Product IDs (the GUID).

Ok. Sorry if I have problem understand this. As I wrote earlier I´m new to this, but one must start somewhere. Is the answer with score +124 going to uninstall the .MSI exactly like a normal uninstallation from controlpanel?, because as I wrote earlier it has installed things that I dont know where they are in the registry, and other things. So I want a COMPLETE uninstallation before installing the new version.

This question shows you how to run an uninstaller before installation in Inno Setup:
How to automatically uninstall previous installed version in Inno Setup?

But it is tailored for an Inno Setup uninstaller. For your previous MSI installation, you need to use msiexec instead. As shown here:
Uninstall an MSI during during Inno Setup uninstall
For MSI installations, I believe the Uninstall registry key does not contain the actual uninstallation command. All you can use the key for is to detect the installation.

The number 2 of the replies here is exactly what I have wanted all along.
But the question now is what to write in the script to get it working?
I´m having trouble understanding this as I am completely new to this.
Can somone please tell me what to write?
Is this a good beginning?
[Code]
begin
ShellExec msiexec /x {B521B31D-6EEB-46B6-94E2-AFDE87C59A20}
end;
[Setup]

No. The first link shows you that you need to implement the CurStepChanged event function and call msiexec using the Exec function.

In the number 2 this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/19806224/850848
it is written:
Once you know the GUID, it can be uninstalled by calling
MsiExec.exe /X{A879B90E-B62C-4DA4-9C3F-79A1A6CFAAF9}
Here {A879B90E-B62C-4DA4-9C3F-79A1A6CFAAF9} is an example for "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages - Visual Studio 2010 Tools".
What I want ot know is HOW to call MsiExec.exe /X{A879B90E-B62C-4DA4-9C3F-79A1A6CFAAF9}
WHAT to write in the script?
should it be [Code] ? Should it be [PrepereToInstall] ? What?
I have looked and looked, but I cant seem to get the correct answer

As I wrote above twice already: the How to automatically uninstall previous installed version in Inno Setup? shows you how to do that. The CurStepChanged and Exec are the keys. + I do not know what you mean by "number 2". But it's probably not relevant anyway.

Number 2 is the thread that you linked to. This one:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/19806224/850848
What you have written twice does NOT apply to uninstalling .MSI if I am correct.
I have written many times that I am totally new to this, and ask for help what to write in the script. the complete code. All you do is give links to threds I have already read.
I do NOT understand that.
All I want to do is execute what you have edited in that thread. This:
Once you know the GUID, it can be uninstalled by calling
MsiExec.exe /X{A879B90E-B62C-4DA4-9C3F-79A1A6CFAAF9}
HOW

No it's indeed not about MSI. But it shows you how to run something at the beginning of the installation. You just need to modify it to run your msiexec command. - I've wrote all that already above.
